# Having problems with php artisan serve using laravel

Tags: php, macos, laravel, terminal, mamp

When I try executing the php artisan serve command in my terminal on laravel 5.0 I'm getting this error.

```
Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I'm on a mac using MAMP, my /etc/hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Comment: You could use php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ but I think I remember reading from Taylor Otwell that Homestead or another VM is the recommended development environment.

Comment: Is something else using port 8000? You could try `php artisan serve --port=8888` and see if that helps.